# QT Start explorer process parameters

Tags: c++, windows, qt

To start an application in QT I can use the process function that is common to most languages, and I can pass parameters in the usual way. However, I am trying to start explorer and pass it a parameter.

So the code:

```
QProcess process;
QString test("/select,\"E:\\Data\\testimage.dat\"");
process.startDetached("explorer.exe", QStringList() << test);
```

should open explorer and highlight the file testimage.dat, in the folder E:\data. However, it opens explorer and highlights documents.

So I tried the same function in C#:

```
string test = "/select,\"E:\\Data\\testimage.dat\"";
Process.Start("explorer.exe", test);
```

This does what I expect, opening explorer and highlighting the file.

From all I see on here, the QT code should do exactly the same. I am using startDetached as the QT version only works the first time saying it is already running.
I know the arguments are the same as I copied and pasted them.

Windows 8.1 and QT5.2 MSVC10

Comment: Use task-mananger & add the command-line column to view the actual command line explorer received

Comment: Sounded a great idea, but for some reason explorer doesn't show that information, it just shows - C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe /factory,{75dff2b7-6936-4c06-a8bb-676a7b00b24b} -Embedding, whether you look at the good or bad. I guess I need to make a dummy app to see the params sent

Comment: ah yes i see that with start->run, try with notepad.exe - will error but shows up in taskmngr

Comment: Solved it - it doesn't make sense but it is the quote marks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved but still puzzled.

In the command line, the entry

```
explorer /select,"E:\Data\testimage.dat"
```

works, but the command

```
explorer /select,E:\Data\testimage.dat
```

doesnt.

A copy of that command line also works in C#. However in QT, the command

```
process.startDetached("EXPLORER.exe", QStringList() << "/select,\"E:\\Data\\testimage.dat\"");
```

works, but when you remove the quotes, the resultant line works fine

```
process.startDetached("EXPLORER.exe", QStringList() << "/select,E:\\Data\\testimage.dat");
```

and when you make a test target to see what the parameters arriving at a target are, the quotes are no longer present when sent from C# or the command line, but they are when sent from QT.